# Getting the IR Tower working with RCX and RobotC

Tags: mindstorms, rcx, robotc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lego Mindstorms RCX RIS 2.0 IR tower Windows 7 / Windows XP driver](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/lego-mindstorms-rcx-ris-2-0-ir-tower-windows-7-windows-xp-driver)

Trying to get RobotC to work with my old RCX 2.0. I'm running windows 7 64 bit. I've connected the IR tower via a Serial to USB cable. I get the error from RobotC when I go to send the firmware "RCX Controler Failed to Respond"

I'm assuming this is because the drivers are for 64 bit only. Has anyone had success running a WindowsXP virtual machine and trying the drivers? Or any luck getting RobotC and the IR tower running on a Win7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question: [Lego Mindstorms RCX RIS 2.0 IR tower Windows 7 / Windows XP driver](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1526/789)
Basically there are no 64bit drivers available and the OP on the question I linked to says he had no luck with an XP VM either.