# RobotC for RCX cannot find USB IR Tower

Tags: programming, rcx, robotc

I have looked for similar question but found null. So here I am asking.

I have Win7, a RobotC fo RCX and Mindstorms for RCX (both are old version, but available free). I borrowed an old LEGO kit (9794 Team Challenge) which lacked some parts. It has RCX 1.0 as controller. I borrowed a USB IR Tower from my friend.

After a well installation, I tried RobotC and was asked to download firmware to RCX brick.
But RobotC cannot communicate with it because it cannot find the port which I plugged the IR tower to. Inside the preference, there are two available USB port recognized.

I swithced between them but RobotC still cannot find the tower. I have been googling this around for almost a month now.

Thanks for any enlightement.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to LEGO Answers :) Are you running a [64bit version of Windows 7?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1526/56)

Comment: hi. no, I'm running 32bit version. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 2):

If you are you using ROBOTC 2 for RCX you need to install the [**separate driver**](http://www.robotc.net/files/rcxdriver.zip) for windows 32bit.  This driver is not included in the ROBOTC install (at least not with version 2.03).

It might also be a good thing to start with a fresh install of [ROBOTC 2.03](http://www.robotc.net/files/ROBOTCforRCX_203.exe).